# My Android TV seems to be rebooting frequently in sleep mode and causing ADB to be disconnected, why?

Tags: android, linux, television

This is the log I got from `adb logcat` when the TV is at sleep mode:

```
03-05 00:50:40.242  9534  9647 I uicksetsdk.son: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
03-05 00:50:40.242  9534  9647 I uicksetsdk.son: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
03-05 00:50:40.271  9534  9647 I uicksetsdk.son: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 19943(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 29(3092KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2295KB/4590KB, paused 110us total 28.982ms
03-05 00:50:40.671  9986  9986 D LIBIWPRIV: Ethernet_WoPacket  ifc_set_Ethernet_listen_port
03-05 00:50:40.671  9986  9986 D MTK PowerHAL: ACFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG : AM_BRDCST_MSG_PRE_POWER_OFF
03-05 00:50:41.178  2902  9975 I BatteryStatsService: In wakeup_callback: suspend aborted
03-05 00:50:41.179  2902  3203 D AlarmManager: Wakeup history#0 Wakeup alarmType=RTC_WAKEUP package=com.mediatek.agent wakeups=1 alarms=1 whenElapsed=0 when=2023-03-04 23:47:47 nowRTC=2023-03-04 23:47:47 workSource=null uid=1000 tag="*walarm*:mtk.intent.rtctimer.set.bgm"
03-05 00:50:41.179  2902  3203 D AlarmManager: Wakeup history#1 Wakeup alarmType=ELAPSED_WAKEUP package=android wakeups=3 alarms=3 whenElapsed=-21s956ms when=-21s956ms nowRTC=2023-03-04 23:48:10 workSource=null uid=1000 tag="*walarm*:DeviceIdleController.deep"
03-05 00:50:41.179  2902  3203 D AlarmManager: Wakeup history#2 Wakeup alarmType=ELAPSED_WAKEUP package=android wakeups=4 alarms=4 whenElapsed=0 when=0 nowRTC=2023-03-05 00:50:32 workSource=null uid=1000 tag="*walarm*:DeviceIdleController.deep"
03-05 00:50:41.179  2902  3203 D AlarmManager: Wakeup alarmType=ELAPSED_WAKEUP package=android wakeups=5 alarms=5 whenElapsed=0 when=0 nowRTC=2023-03-05 00:50:41 workSource=null uid=1000 tag="*walarm*:DeviceIdleController.deep"
03-05 00:50:41.180  2902  2980 W AlarmManager: Unrecognized alarm listener com.android.server.DeviceIdleController$4@2730dbf
03-05 00:50:41.225  9810  9990 W adbd    : timed out while waiting for FUNCTIONFS_BIND, trying again
03-05 00:50:41.225  9810  9990 I adbd    : UsbFfs: connection terminated: monitor thread finished
03-05 00:50:41.225  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfs: already offline
03-05 00:50:41.225  9810  9810 I adbd    : destroying transport UsbFfs
03-05 00:50:41.225  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection being destroyed
03-05 00:50:41.268  9810  9811 I adbd    : opening control endpoint /dev/usb-ffs/adb/ep0
03-05 00:50:41.268  9810  9811 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection constructed
03-05 00:50:41.437  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: for GCM case,update port info
03-05 00:50:41.437  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: wopacket Sony behavior(for GCM case,update port info)
03-05 00:50:41.437  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: enable WoPacket before power off
03-05 00:50:41.437  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXXenter: AP 7668 a_nw_wlan_set_ip_and_port_to_driver
03-05 00:50:41.437  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXX AP first clear all ethernet port
03-05 00:50:41.437  9993  9993 D LIBIWPRIV: Ethernet_WoPacket  ifc_clear_listen_port
03-05 00:50:41.438  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXXXXXget valid Ex v4port 40918
03-05 00:50:41.438  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: (WOWL)tcp v6 port2 = set_wow_tcp 0 8008,8009,1900,40918
03-05 00:50:41.438  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXXethernet tcp port0 is 8008
03-05 00:50:41.438  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXXethernet tcp port1 is 8009
03-05 00:50:41.438  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXXethernet tcp port2 is 1900
03-05 00:50:41.438  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXXethernet tcp port3 is 40918
03-05 00:50:42.273  9810  9991 W adbd    : timed out while waiting for FUNCTIONFS_BIND, trying again
03-05 00:50:42.273  9810  9991 I adbd    : UsbFfs: connection terminated: monitor thread finished
03-05 00:50:42.273  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfs: already offline
03-05 00:50:42.273  9810  9810 I adbd    : destroying transport UsbFfs
03-05 00:50:42.273  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection being destroyed
03-05 00:50:42.338  9810  9811 I adbd    : opening control endpoint /dev/usb-ffs/adb/ep0
03-05 00:50:42.339  9810  9811 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection constructed
03-05 00:50:42.976  9993  9993 D LIBIWPRIV: Ethernet_WoPacket  ifc_set_Ethernet_listen_port
03-05 00:50:42.977  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: (WOWL)udp port = set_wow_udp 0 5353
03-05 00:50:42.977  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: XXXXXethernet udp port0 is 5353
03-05 00:50:43.341  9810  9994 W adbd    : timed out while waiting for FUNCTIONFS_BIND, trying again
03-05 00:50:43.341  9810  9994 I adbd    : UsbFfs: connection terminated: monitor thread finished
03-05 00:50:43.342  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfs: already offline
03-05 00:50:43.342  9810  9810 I adbd    : destroying transport UsbFfs
03-05 00:50:43.342  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection being destroyed
03-05 00:50:43.388  9810  9811 I adbd    : opening control endpoint /dev/usb-ffs/adb/ep0
03-05 00:50:43.389  9810  9811 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection constructed
03-05 00:50:44.391  9810  9995 W adbd    : timed out while waiting for FUNCTIONFS_BIND, trying again
03-05 00:50:44.391  9810  9995 I adbd    : UsbFfs: connection terminated: monitor thread finished
03-05 00:50:44.391  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfs: already offline
03-05 00:50:44.391  9810  9810 I adbd    : destroying transport UsbFfs
03-05 00:50:44.391  9810  9810 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection being destroyed
03-05 00:50:44.458  9810  9811 I adbd    : opening control endpoint /dev/usb-ffs/adb/ep0
03-05 00:50:44.458  9810  9811 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection constructed
03-05 00:50:44.515  9993  9993 D LIBIWPRIV: Ethernet_WoPacket  ifc_set_Ethernet_listen_port
03-05 00:50:44.515  9993  9993 D MTK PowerHAL: ACFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG : AM_BRDCST_MSG_PRE_POWER_OFF
```

ADB is highly possible to be disconnected after the last line is printed.
Android version: 10
Kernal version: 4.19.75
Because everytime this happens I see different PID for `PowerHAL`, I guess the TV is actaully being rebooted fequently?

I unplugged the HDMI cabal, reset the system, but issue still there.
Does anyone know what could possibly be the reason, or how can I troubleshoot this issue?
If, in the worst case scenario, this is a correct behavior, how can I bypass it?

Comment: This site is for programming questions.

Comment: @user16320675 removed

Answer (score 1):

See that bug is already fixed: [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/mediatek/wembley-sepolicy/) also note that you shouldn't have the security settings and/or automatic shutdown configured.

Comment: in which commit? is it applicable for android 10?